# How do I store the name of files from a git repo after cloning it to my system using ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I want to store the name of files (only names) in a file say, "name.txt" which are less than 90 days old from a git repo after cloning it to my system using ruby script. How do I do that ? Also How can I use git commands in my ruby script ?

Comment: Have a look at `git ls-files`. Not sure if it satisfies your 90 day requirement.

Comment: You can use a library like this: https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git which allows you to read files easily from git - then simply filter based on age. my two cents.

Comment: git ls-files will list all the files.  This command will list the files less than 90 days ago "git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log --since="90 days ago" -1 --format="%e{}" {} | sort "  but when I put this in my ruby script , it does not work.  The error generated is "xargs" is not recognised as internal or external command . Any help ?

Comment: Or may be I'm not using proper syntax. 

cmd='git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log --since="90 days ago" -1 --format="%e{}" {} | sort > name.txt'
system(cmd)

Comment: Showing us your Ruby script is more likely to result in someone telling you how to modify it to accomplish your goal. Just saying "do this thing for me" is not the right approach. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.